# Access external file for serverless variable for Amazon Web Server AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I'm want to read variable in external json file in my serverless file. But I get this error:

```
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  Invalid variable reference syntax for variable serverless-gf. You can only reference env vars, options, & files. You can check our docs for more info.

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Forums:        forum.serverless.com
     Chat:          gitter.im/serverless/serverless

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     linux
     Node Version:           6.13.1
     Serverless Version:     1.26.1
```

This in my code in serverless.yml:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  profile: ${opt:profile, ${file(./config/serverless_config.json):profile}}
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
```

This is my ./config/serverless_config.json:

```
{
    "profile":"serverless-gf"
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hey! Hope the issue has been already resolved, but just in case. 
I've checked your code with the serverless version `1.38.0` and it works absolutely fine.